# Strobe light camera parameters? Why is My app crashing?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-camera

I have a couple of apps on Google.

In these app, I have this strobe light that runs when a user presses a button. 
The problem is, when I switch activities, the app crashes. I get some anr's because of the camera's parameters being set on whilst the user is pressing back. Meaning when they go to the next activity that asks for the camera, the app crashes. I even have the application downloaded on my phone and sometimes my phone stops responding. I was trying to figure out why my own phone was starting to act up and I found out that it's my app that's causing these problems.

Here's my baby! I bugged you guys for like 2 weeks trying to figure out how to make this particular implementation.

```
    public void strobeTimer182() {
    superStrobe = new CountDownTimer(857, 1) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (millisUntilFinished % 2 == 0) {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();

            } else {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();
                 crazy.nextInt(265)));
            }
            if (millisUntilFinished == 0) {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();

            }

        }
```

I've read that it's because the camera's parameters are On when the phone expects them to be off.

My question is. Why is this happening. You can see in the code that the if statement should turn it completely of.

here is some of the code provides about the error.

this is my onStart()

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
    // turnOffFlash();
}
```

and the getCamera() "the button" is the toggle camera on button. so when the app starts.. you have to turn it on. Some phones do not work well with getting the camera so i figured i had to check first.. when you press other buttons.. music plays and the strobe plays for 857 milliseconds.. as you can see.

public void getCamera() {

```
Context context = this;
// Retrieve application packages that are currently installed
// on the device which includes camera, GPS etc.
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!"); // Toast a message to let the
    // user know that camera is not // installed in the device
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Your device doesn't have camera!",         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    button.setEnabled(false);

    // Return from the method, do nothing after this code block
    return;
} else {

    camera = Camera.open();
    p = camera.getParameters();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you release the camera when your activity suspends or pauses.  This is important because only one activity is allowed to own access to the camera at a time, and if your activity never releases it before it dies, then your camera is effectively useless until you reboot your phone.

Also, make sure to call `.cancel()` on your CountDownTimer

```
// YourActivity.java
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    if(superStrobe != null){
        superStrobe.cancel();
    }

    if(camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I spent some time and built your app's effect and made sure it handled itself cleanly.  Nice strobe!  So, here are some things you really need to keep in mind:

1. The camera requires special care in handling, and as such you need to be meticulous about how you setup and tear down your Activity.
2. It will help you a lot to use specific methods that are designed to safely handle your resources.  Try never to handle your camera, or your timer unless you're doing it through methods that safely check what they're doing before they try to do it.
3. Generally, it's best to do your Activity's setup in `.onResume()` and its teardown in `.onPause()`

I'll skip over the parts that you seem to understand already, but call out some very important considerations for you and for anyone else who finds this.

Because handling the Android camera is a bit perilous, you'll want methods like these, and they should come in pairs.  One to create your assets, and another to clean them up:

```
// Ways to safely access the camera...
safelyAcquireCamera()
safelyReleaseCamera()

// Ways to safely access the timer...
startTimer()
stopTimer()

// Ways to setup your button...
setupButton()

// Special error handling code that makes sure to clean up the Activity if it crashes.
setupUncaughtExceptionHandler()
restoreOriginalUncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

and you'll want variables like these

```
Camera camera;
Camera.Parameters cameraParameters;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
UncaughtExceptionHandler originalExceptionHandler;
boolean timerIsStarted = false;
```

I'll break this down for you.  This may seem fairly *long* but there are a lot of concepts here:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    this.setupUncaughtExceptionHandler(); 
        // ^^ Super important!  ^^
        // This saves you if you crash!


    boolean didAcquireCamera = safelyAcquireCamera();

    setupButton(didAcquireCamera);
        // ^^ Set up your button, letting the 
        // method know if you succeeded in acquiring the camera.
        // you probably know how to implement this already. 

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    stopTimer();
        // FIRST stop your timer.  Even though the timer has logic that
        // accounts for you doing this out of order, it's still correct 
        // to stop your running action first.

    safelyReleaseCamera();
        // Now you should release your camera using your safe method.

    releaseButtons();
        // Release your buttons...

    restoreOriginalUncaughtExceptionHandler(); 
        // ^^ Since you safely cleaned up your Activity
        // it is s time to restore the Exception Handler.
}

protected void stopTimer() {
    // This method gives you a safe way to stop the timer.
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
        timerIsStarted = false;
    }
}

protected void safelyReleaseCamera() {

    // This method gives you a safe way to release the camera.
    if (camera != null) {

        // You probably want to make sure to turn the flash off
        // if you had it on already!
        if (cameraParameters != null) {
            cameraParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
        }

        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        cameraParameters = null;

    }

}

protected boolean safelyAcquireCamera() {
    safelyReleaseCamera();
      // ^^ It's very important to make sure your app DOES NOT
      // have a stray camera before you try to acquire a new one!
      // Be absolutely sure to call safe release before you try to 
      // call Camera.open(); here.


    /**
     * You seem to know how to acquire the camera already.  Just
     * return true if you succeeded and false if you didn't.
     **/


    return camera != null;
}


protected void startTimer(long millisInTheFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    stopTimer();
    timerIsStarted = true;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInTheFuture, countDownInterval) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (camera == null || cameraParameters == null) {
                stopTimer();
                return;
                  // Clearly things have gone awry if you lost your camera!  
                  // Bail Out.
            }

            /**
             * Do your strobing like normal in here...
             **/

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerIsStarted = false;
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}

protected void setupButtons(boolean didAcquireCamera){

    /**
     *  You seem to have a good handle on
     *  how to set up a button.  Make it so!
     **/

}

protected void releaseButtons(){
    // And here you should safely set all your button handlers to null!
}

/*****************
 * Safety Methods
 *   This might be advanced, but I'll try to make it simple.
 *****************/

private void setupUncaughtExceptionHandler() {

    restoreOriginalUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        // ^^ Ensure that you're in as close to a default state as you can.

    Thread currentlyRunningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    originalExceptionHandler = currentlyRunningThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        // ^^ This is the thing that happens when your app normally crashes.
        // You'll be giving it a new, special set of instructions in this case,
        // but you'll still want to hold onto the default implmenetation.

    currentlyRunningThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

            stopTimer();
            safelyReleaseCamera();
                // ^^ You don't know how or why you crashed.
                // So call your safe disposal methods here!

            releaseButtons();

            if(originalExceptionHandler != null){
                originalExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
                    // Now make sure you call the original handler so that 
                    // Android does its normal crash thing.
            }

            thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(originalExceptionHandler);
                // And restore the original crash behavior to be the default.

        }

    });
}

private void restoreOriginalUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    if (originalExceptionHandler != null) {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(originalExceptionHandler);
        originalExceptionHandler = null;
    }
}
```

You'll probably have to scroll that code area above.

Hopefully this is helpful for people of various experience levels.  Some of this might seem like black magic but I've done my best to explain the *why* behind it.

Comment: ok!! i was using the if (camera != null) {
   camera.release();
   camera = null;
  } in the onDestroy() so.. let me fix this now.. thanks man!! @scriptocalypse

Comment: onDestroy() is definitely not soon enough.  Releasing the camera the instant the activity stops doing anything is the best course of action, and that's generally onPause().

Comment: that actually made more problems. . @scriptocalypse you see where it says  camera.setParameters(p); right under the } else { .. it says unhandled exception. that doesn't make any sense cause it was just working.. i know the camera is not automatically set to on pause when the activity starts..

Comment: See the edit.  You also need to cancel your superStrobe.

Comment: i thought i could edit you answer but i guess i can't.. please check out my revised question.. i appreciate your help but those solutions are not working.. but i'm sure you know the solution. just maybe you need to see the code better. @scriptocalypse

Comment: I'm at work now so can't answer until this evening, but i might suggest two things.  Use `onResume()` instead of onStart and always check if your camera and your p value are != null before you try to do anything with them inside of `onTick()`

Comment: bro your amazing! I was not expecting you to come back and comment on this issue. Nor was expecting you to give such a detailed answer. It doesn't even matter if it works not, the effort shown to answer the question is ridiculous. You should own a company! People who're selfless like you deserve power. I would trust you with it. I have to study it really cause i'm self taught. So let me stop blabbing and figure this out. Cheers! @scriptocalypse

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  I tested this on a nexus 4, and freely could open, close, strobe, and switch to other apps that responsibly handle the camera without issue.  I didn't post the entire source obviously, but everything important is there.

Comment: i promise i'm almost done bothering you .. 
@scriptocalypse again thank you for you help

Comment: It looks like the big issue is that you never assigned an onclick listener to any button, so even if you touch the button nothing happens.  Also you look like you are going to call countDownTimer.onFinish() manually immediately after you start the timer. Remove that call.

Comment: ok .. check out that .. new protected void startTimer @scriptocalypse

Comment: hey man, @scriptocalypse i Know it's the weekend but when you see this can you look at my revised answer because i changed the startTimer() it's still not working.. it'g giving me errors.